# SVG width exceeds the div

Tags: html, css, svg

We have a generated SVG graphic inside our web application. The problem is that the svg can get very wide and then it may exceed the html content.

The header is defined as 100% width, but this 100% width does not count for the svg size. With firebug we see that the  containing the svg is not that large and so the html page thinks it is of this width. But the svg is much larger than that.

How can I make the  take the whole size of the SVG image?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you want the page to expand to fit the SVG, or the SVG to shrink to fit the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width by using getBBox like this: `$('.yoursvgclassname')[0].getBBox().width;`
Do this in an onload function and set the width of your navbar there.

If you want to cut:
Use `overflow: scroll` on your SVG graphic. 
This will clip it at the edge of your container and add a Scrollbar.

Comment: I would like to have the opposite - make the rest of the content also 100% large -  not having a second scrollbar inside the page. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean the navigationbar?

Comment: Yes that the navigation bar has the 100% width (same width as the svg)